# Haskell Writing Class Basics

Tags: function, class, haskell

I've been running into this problem constantly I'm trying to learn Haskell and right now learning classes. I'm trying to make a function where you enter in three numbers and if they equal each other then returns a True Bool else returns a False Bool.

I understand I need a class like this:

```
allTheSame :: a -> a -> a -> Bool
```

However I'm constantly get confused what I should put in the function itself after writing

```
allTheSame x y z =
```

I've had this problem before with a function I wrote about showing the minimum value of a 3 variable function. I did this by using the base min function twice like this:

```
min3 x y z = min x $ min y z
```

But How would I do it when there is no base function to use? Would really appreciate it as I've been hung up on this problem for hours.

Thanks Allot!

Comment: ever heard of an if-else statement?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but this question and the previous one look like you are using SO as a way of doing your homework for you. Be aware that too many low quality questions may lead to a question ban.

Comment: There is a base function to use.  It's called (==).  Try hoogling for a -> a -> Bool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of the word *class* is incorrect.  In Haskell a class, or typeclass as its sometimes called, is a specification of functions that a type must support, somewhat like an interface in OOP.  What you need is a *function*.  Functions take values as arguments, and in this case you need a function that takes 3 numbers and checks to see if they're all the same.  What function (or operator, which are also functions) do you use to check for equality?  The `==` operator is what you're looking for.

So how do you use the `==` operator?  The easy way to find out is to load up GHCi and enter

```
> :type (==)
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

(don't type the `>`, it indicates the start of the input)

What's this `Eq a =>` doing in the type signature?  It means that `==` takes two arguments of type `a` that implement the `Eq` typeclass.  This is the only constraint that you need on the `allSame` function, so to fix the type signature:

```
allSame :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allSame x y z = ???
```

That small change makes all the difference in the world, without it you couldn't write this function.

So how would you implement it?  The `==` function only takes two arguments and returns a `Bool`, and you have 3 arguments.  We need to check for

```
x == y
x == z
y == z
```

But, thanks to the transitive property of equality, if `x == y`, and `y == z`, then `x == z` as well, so you don't need to check all three, just two of them.  So now we know that our definition must contain the expressions `x == y` and `y == z` somewhere in it, but they need to be combined together to produce a single result.  Since we need both of those conditions to be true, that would require a logical AND, the `&&` operator.  So finally, we can write it as

```
allSame :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allSame x y z = (x == y) && (y == z)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you'll need to use `==` so our type is

```
 allSame :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
 allSame x y z = ???
```

Now we can test whether `x` and `y` are equal with `x == y`. We have

```
 allSame x y z = if x == y then ??? else False
```

Where `???` means `x` and `y` are the same and we need to make sure `x` and `z` are the same.

```
 allSame x y z = if x == y then x == z else False
```

This can be simplified with `&&` to

```
 allSame x y z = x == y && y == z
```

Answer (score 0):

My Haskell is a little rusty, but I hope I can point you in the right direction.

Given the signature `allTheSame :: a -> a -> a -> Bool` x y z in would be the first 3 a's, and the final value would be the bool, so something like `allTheSame x y z = True`.

I think what may confuse you is that Haskell isn't really meant for procedural operations.  Everything must be computed "all at once".  However you can organize your logic so it isn't all one line with things like `where` clauses and guards.

Ex. this one:

```
allSame :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> a -> Bool

allSame x y z = fstSame && sndSame
                where
                    fstSame = x == y
                    sndSame = y == z
```

You might find some more useful ways to structure in [Learn You a Haskell's section on Syntax in Functions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions), plus it's always insightful to look at [Haskell's Standard Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html).